# PyTorch get_device_capability() Output Explanation

Tags: pytorch

when running `torch.cuda.get_device_capability()` on my GTX 1070 I get the following output: `(6, 1)`.

Could someone explain what this means?

Comment: Do [the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html) not suffice? `Returns the major and minor cuda capability of the device` So those are presumably CUDA version numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment, those are actully your GPU's compute capability version/indicator.
To put it simply, it describes the features supported by your GPU. You can also view your GPU compute capability using GPU-Z if you are on windows.
For more information concerning the exact feature set differences you can have a look [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications).
[image]
As you can see here, based on, these allows the developers to know which feature-set is available to them and thus enable some features for some hardwares if they support it and otherwise fall back to other implementations of them.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973174/what-does-compute-capability-mean-w-r-t-cuda/11974822) may be useful as well.